# How to link page from one app to another app

Tags: html, django, forms, url

I'm new to django and I'm building a project "myblog" which has "blog" app in which I have created a base.html file which contain nav bar list of About and contact.I also created a "sendemail" app in same "myblog" project and I placed "email.html" contact file in templates directory of "sendemail" app, then what should be the href link in base.html file of "blog" app to access email.html file in "sendemail" app.

This is base.html file in blog app of templates directory.

```
{% load static %}

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
  <head>

    <title>Stand For Christ</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/base.css' %}">
    <link
      href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,700"
      rel="stylesheet">
    <meta name="google" content="notranslate" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css"
      integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    />

  </head>

  <body>
    <style>
      body {
        font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
        font-size: 17px;
        background-color: #fdfdfd;
      }

    .shadow{
           box-shadow:  0 4px 2px -2px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);

       }



      .btn-danger {
        color: #fff;
        background-color: #1d2671;
        border-color: #1d2671;
      }

     .masthead {
              background: #1d2671;
              height: auto;
              padding-bottom: 15px;
              box-shadow: 0 16px 48px #E3E7EB;
              padding-top: 10px;
    }
    </style>


    <!-- Navigation -->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light shadow" id="mainNav">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <a  class="navbar-brand" href="{% url 'home' %}" style="color:#1d2671;font-size:25px" >Stand For Christ Ministries</a>
        <button
          class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right"
          type="button"
          data-toggle="collapse"
          data-target="#navbarResponsive"
          aria-controls="navbarResponsive"
          aria-expanded="false"
          aria-label="Toggle navigation"
        >
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>

        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarResponsive">
          <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">

            <li class="nav-item text-black">
              <a
                class="nav-link text-black font-weight-bold"
                href="about.html"
                >About</a>
            </li>
            
            <li class="nav-item text-black">
              <a
                class="nav-link text-black font-weight-bold"
                href="#what should be the link here."
                >Contact</a
              >
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    </nav>


            {% block content %}
          <!-- Content Goes here -->
            {{ content | safe }}
            {% endblock content %}

    <!-- Footer -->
    <footer class="py-3 bg-green">
              <p class="m-0 text-dark text-center ">Copyright &copy; Stand For Christ Ministries</p>
    </footer>

  </body>
</html>
```

This is urls.py file in "sendemail" app

```
# sendemail/urls.py
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path

from .views import contactView, successView

urlpatterns = [
    path('contact/', contactView, name='contact'),
    path('success/', successView, name='success'),
]
```

This is views.py file of "sendemail" app

## sendemail/views.py

```
from django.core.mail import send_mail, BadHeaderError
from django.http import HttpResponse, HttpResponseRedirect
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from .forms import ContactForm

def contactView(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        form = ContactForm()
    else:
        form = ContactForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            subject = form.cleaned_data['subject']
            from_email = form.cleaned_data['from_email']
            message = form.cleaned_data['message']
            try:
                send_mail(subject, message, from_email, ['mahesh.usa16@gmail.com'])
            except BadHeaderError:
                return HttpResponse('Invalid header found.')
            return redirect('success')
    return render(request, "email.html", {'form': form})

def successView(request):
    return HttpResponse('Success! Thank you for your message.')
```

please go to base.html file where contact nav bar link is there and read the comment there,what should be the link there?

Answer (score 0):

In your "sendemail" app urls.py file add before urlpatterns

```
app_name = 'sendemail'
```

and then in base.html use

```
href="{% url 'sendemail:contact' %}"
```

Follow this to learn more: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/http/urls/#reversing-namespaced-urls

Comment: Thank you very much vineet it worked for me, now contact form is visible.

Comment: can you help me one more time, this time when i submit contact from after filling details I'm not getting 'Success! Thank you for your message.' HttpResponse. what should i do.

Comment: That depends on your email.html, In there when you are submitting your form, the contactView must be called with POST method, so I do not think you need succesView for anything.

In you contactView POST code(else part), change return redirect('success') to how you want user to see the response